# Subversion stops working on http:// checkouts

Tags: 10.10

I've upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 and subversion checkout from http:// just refuses to work anymore. Always timeouts.

I tried a 10.10 Live version and that *works* and all my packages are upto date.

The symptom is:

```
hendry@x201 tmp$ svn co http://tc.labs.opera.com/svn/apis/XMLHttpRequest/
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://tc.labs.opera.com/svn/apis/XMLHttpRequest': could not connect to server (http://tc.labs.opera.com)
```

I am out of ideas since subversion is too difficult to debug. Do I just re-install everything? Anyone seen a similar problem?

```
svn, version 1.6.12 (r955767)
```

I strongly suspect it has some thing to do with the neon library.

```
ii  libneon27                             0.29.3-2                                          An HTTP and WebDAV client library
ii  libneon27-gnutls                      0.29.3-2                                          An HTTP and WebDAV client library (GnuTLS enabled)
```

Comment: Are u facing the issue for all repo or just this one?

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me - I am also using 10.10. Can you browse to the repository in a web browser OK?

Have you tried again later? Maybe it was a temporary problem with their website that has since been fixed.

Another possibility is that there is something in your subversion config causing an issue. Maybe you could try

```
mv ~/.subversion ~/.subversion_old
```

And then try the checkout again.

Comment: agree with Hamish Downer . it  works me too

Answer (score 2):

I cannot replicate this issue with the same version of svn and libneon27. However, there is a related bug report over [at Debian](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=531338). From their discussion it seems that libneon 0.29.3-2 should have fixed the problem. It's possible there has been a regression, but considering multiple other users cannot replicate your problem with the latest version of the package I feel like this is relatively unlikely.

There is a workaround suggested on the Debian bug tracker. Try editing `~/.subversion/servers` and adding the line:

`http-library=serf`

To the end of the file. If this does not correct your issue it becomes even more unlikely that libneon has anything to do with your specific issue.

Answer (score -2):

I think the subversion adress is wrong (http://tc.labs.opera.com/svn/apis/XMLHttpRequest/)
When i browsed the http://tc.labs.opera.com/ there is no svn library

Comment: The URL is correct try browsing http://tc.labs.opera.com/svn/.